# Jquery filter issue - filtering on parent and adding event to child

Tags: jquery

I have some sections on the page, and in the code I have inherited it uses a filter to add a click event to specific sections. When clicking a section it then reveals a comments box.

```
$('section[data-actionid]').filter(function () {
    var tpe = parseInt($(this).attr('data-actiontypeid'), 10);
    //allow inner if not a like and not a wallpostcomment, i.e. end of the line
    return (tpe % 100 !== Tm.action.Comment &&( tpe < 10000 || tpe > 20000));
}).on('click', function () {
    var actionid = $(this).data('actionid');
    var lic = $(this).find('li[data-actionid]:not([data-parentid])');
    if (!lic || lic.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var li = lic[0];
    if (actionid) {
        GetTMActionInner(li, actionid, objid, vwrsid, successGetTMActionInnerCallback, failureGetTMActionInnerCallback);
    }
});
```

Ideally I want to do this on the click of a specific link, with the class TMComment, but am unsure how to combine the two.

Do I need to add a filter to the `anchor tag` with that class, and then get the data it needs to filter from its parents section or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was yes. I targeted the anchor, and used `closest()` to find the parent section